# Ruby: Ocra not building standalone executables from ruby scripts even when provided the gems path as argument

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, executable, ocra

As I stated in the Question title, I have installed Ruby 3.0 version in Windows 10 64Bit OS and I have coded this program for Password generation and copying the generated password to clipboard(PasswordGenerator.rb):

```
require 'clipboard'
CHARS = ('0'..'9').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('!'..'?').to_a
def GeneratePassword(length=16)
    return CHARS.sort_by{rand}.join[0...length.to_i]
end
Clipboard.copy (GeneratePassword 15)
```

And I have also installed all the necessary gems that could be needed as dependencies and even sub-dependencies with these:

```
gem install ocra
gem install --install-dir ./gems thor ftools nokogiri rubygems clipboard
```

But the second command above installed all the dependencies inside `(dir of PasswordGenerator.rb)/gems/gems` directory instead of `(dir of PasswordGenerator.rb)/gems/` folder, but I ignored that as maybe `gem install --install-dir` sucked once due to glitch.

But now as I try to build standalone executable from PasswordGenerator.rb with `ocra` in the same directory it gives me this error. I want a permanent solution of this issue with understanding of why and how `ocra` wasn't able to add the gems even when specified in the build command the extra paths like `ocra PasswordGenerator.rb ./gems/gems` and threw this error:

```
path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:693:in `block (3 levels) in find_gem_files': undefined method `relative_path_from' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:693:in `select'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:693:in `block (2 levels) in find_gem_files'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:685:in `each'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:685:in `block in find_gem_files'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:627:in `each'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:627:in `find_gem_files'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:755:in `build_exe'
        from path/to/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/ocra-1.3.11/bin/ocra:1231:in `block in <top (required)>'
```